# Must Return a Value; Vector of Integers; Word Count

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, return

I'm having some problems with a program that I'm writing where you find the count of words in a file. The issue I'm having is with my function "get_word_counts" in my cpp. I'm continually getting an message in Visual Studio that states "error C4716: 'TextCounter::get_word_counts': must return a value", despite the fact that I do, in fact, return a value at the end of the function.

Can someone help me understand what the issue with this is? I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to figure out exactly what the problem is. Perhaps it's something simple, but I just can't see it.

I'll post below my cpp file as well as the header:

**cpp:**

```
#include"TextCounter.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>


/*
    Constructor takes in the filename and builds the map.
*/
TextCounter::TextCounter(std::string file):
    filename(file) {
    // Build the input list.
    parse_file();
}

/*
    Get the count of each word in the document. 

    If a word doesn't occur in the document, put 0.
*/
std::vector<int> TextCounter::get_word_counts(const std::vector<std::string>& words) {
    // TODO: Finish this method.

    std::vector<int> result;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator iter; 

    for (auto const &i : words) {
        iter = TextCounter::frequency.find(i);

        if (iter == frequency.end()) {
            result.push_back(0);
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(iter->second);
        }
    }
    return result;
}





// Add a word to the map.
// Check to see if the word exists, if so, increment
// otherwise create a new entry and set it to 1.
void TextCounter::add_word(std::string word) {
    // COMP: finished this method.

            //Look if it's already there.
            if (frequency.find(word) == frequency.end()) // Then we've encountered the word for a first time.
                frequency[word] = 1; // Initialize it to 1.
            else // Then we've already seen it before..
                frequency[word]++; // Increment it.
}


// Parse an input file.
// Return -1 if there is an error.
int TextCounter::parse_file() {
    // Local variables.
    std::ifstream inputfile;  // ifstream for reading from input file.

    // Open the filename specified for input.
    inputfile.open (filename);

    // Tokenize the input.
    // Read one character at a time.
    // If the character is not in a-z or A-Z, terminate current string.
    char c;
    char curr_str[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int str_i = 0;  // Index into curr_str.
    bool flush_it = false;  // Whether we have a complete string to flush.

    while (inputfile.good()) {
        // Read one character, convert it to lowercase.
        inputfile.get(c);
        c = tolower(c);

        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            // c is a letter.
            curr_str[str_i] = c;
            str_i++;

            // Check over-length string.
            if (str_i >= MAX_STRING_LEN) {
                flush_it = true;
            }
        } else {
            // c is not a letter.
            // Create a new string if curr_str is non-empty.
            if (str_i>0) {
                flush_it = true;
            }
        }

        if (flush_it) {
            // Create the new string from curr_str.
            std::string the_str(curr_str,str_i);
            // std::cout << the_str << std::endl;

            // COMP: Insert code to handle new entries or increment an existing entry.
            TextCounter::add_word(the_str);

            // Reset state variables.
            str_i = 0;
            flush_it = false;
        }
    }

    // Close input file.
    inputfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**header:**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 256
#define DICT_SIZE 20000

class TextCounter {
    public:
        explicit TextCounter(std::string file = "");

        // Get the counts of a vector of words.
        std::vector<int> get_word_counts(const std::vector<std::string>& words);

    private:    
        // Name of the input file.
        std::string filename;

        // COMP: Implement a data structure to keep track of each word and the
        // number of times that word occurs in the document.
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int> frequency;

        // Parse an input file.
        int parse_file();

        // Add a word to the map.
        void add_word(std::string word);
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Aside from the fact that returning a `vector<int>` as a value is an _expensive_ operation (it would be faster to return a reference) - I don't see what's wrong either. _Expensive_ is surely no syntax error.

Comment: @Aganju: It won't be expensive cos' it'll RVOed away.

Comment: Not reproducible. VS 2015 can compile your code without problem.